# Is it wrong to terminate a c-string with 0 instead of '\0'?

Tags: c, string

C-strings are null-terminated which means that in a char-array, the char at index `strlen()` is a byte with all bits set to 0. I've seen code where, instead of `'\0'`, the integer `0` is used. But since `sizeof(int) > sizeof(char)`, this might actually write beyond the allocated space for the array - am I wrong? Or does the compiler implicitely cast a an `int` to `char` in such a situation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes  you are wrong - the zero value will be truncated. After all, if you write:

```
char c = 0;
```

you would not expect the compiler to write beyond the bounds of the variable c, I hope. If you write something like this:

```
char c = 12345;
```

then the compiler should warn you of the truncation. GCC produces:

```
c.c:2: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion
```

but still nothing will be written beyond the bounds of the variable.

Answer (score 13):

When storing the value `0` in an array of `char`s, then the int will be implicitly converted to char.

Actually, the type of `'\0'` is `int` (contrary to what one may expect), so `somechararray[x]=0` and `somechararray[x]='\0'` are semantically equivalent.

Personally, I prefer to go with `'\0'`, to make it more clear that I'm dealing with a string.